# How do I get device related info programmatically like model number or IMSI , MSISDN while developing codenameone app

Tags: codenameone

I am developing a codename app and need to capture device model ,imsi and msisdn information so that i can send data depending on this information.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try Display.getInstance().getUdid() and Display.getInstance().getMsisdn() you can also use Display.getInstance().getProperty(...) for more properties.