# How do I get device model name and device ip address programmatically while developing codenameone app?

Tags: codenameone

I want to get programmatically the following information: device model name and it's current ip address. I've read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25228750/1956299) to similar question, but I can't find how to get information necessary to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Display.getProperty` method has several keys that might be of interest in extracting device information, OS version/type etc.

The ip address might not be relevant inside the operator NAT but you can use something like `Socket.getHostOrIP()`, it should work on some platforms.

Comment: I see with .getProperty(...) method I can use following keys to get info: 
AppName, User-Agent, AppVersion, Platform, OS, OSVer. But there is no key to get device model name.

Comment: The user agent option is pretty much the best way to analyze this.